# Pulling Data automatically, and keeping it Dynamic

Tags: google-apps-script

Lets say I have data on an Amazon S3 Server, and I need to pull specific parts of that data into a Google sheet. It needs to update dynamically based on new inputs into the bucket, but everything in the bucket is simply a csv and as such is not dynamic.

Is there a Google Apps Script that I can write to run from Google Sheets that can pull data from a bucket or server?

Comment: Does the bucket or the server support some type of an API for accessing it's data?

Comment: What do you mean "keeping it dynamic" Do your csv data have timestamps?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a google script at all.  I would just use the google sheets function

```
importdata(url)
```

You mentioned that you needed a subset of the data, so hide the sheet above and then create a reference in another sheet for the fields that you need.  Easy peasy -- then just make sure that your sheet is set to recalculate on the interval that you need.

Edit:

Pulling data on an interval:

I believe if you go to `'File' --> spreadsheet settings --> Calculation` and then select the Recalculation interval to `on change and every hour` (or minute), it will automatically pull the data again on that interval.

If you want to have more control over when the data refreshes though you in the above step, set the calculation to `on change' only and then add the following script:

```
function refreshdata() {
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('[sheetname goes here]').getRange('A1').setValue('=importdata("[your url here]")')
}
```

and then add a trigger for the function `refreshdata` to run on the interval you want the data to be refreshed on.

Comment: How would you make sure it refreshes?

Comment: @Aerials I believe setting the 'Recalculation' value of the spreadsheet will do this on an interval, but I added a small script above that will let you do it with a bit more control using a trigger.

Comment: So part of the problem I have is that the data in the S3 Bucket is automatically updating. This happens by deleting the files and then repopulating the folder with the new information for the day. I know how I would pull the data if the files kept their original name, but the name and reference is constantly changing based on the date. Is there a script I could run that would pull a different URL based on the date?

Comment: Is that data file the only file that is in that directory or does it have a predictable name?  Would there be a way to set up a notification to go out when the contents of the directory changes?  At that point you could set up your script with either a `doGet(e)` / `doPost(e)` and retrieve the url from the notification?

Comment: Here is the information on the [enabling S3 notifications in Amazon's help docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-event-notifications.html)